# SQL ERROR = Unknown column 'Backpack' in 'where clause'...tips?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am taking an intro class to PHP and mySQL. This code am writing is trying to return more information from a database when I click on a link from a table with less information from the same database. For some reason I cannot get the code to work after endless hours of research and testing. I would greatly appreciate any help or tips.

SQL:

```
#stops table from being duplicated
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS stuff;
 #create table for stuff
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stuff (
  id INT primary key auto_increment, 
  location_id INT not null,
  name TEXT not null,
  description TEXT not null,
  create_date DATETIME not null,
  update_date DATETIME not null,
  room TEXT,
  owner TEXT,
  finder TEXT,
  status SET('found','lost','claimed') not null
);

INSERT INTO stuff (location_id, name, description, create_date, update_date, room, owner, finder, status)
    VALUES(2, "Cell phone", "Black iPhone 5s, scratches on screen with a black otterbox", now(), now(), "", "Zach Tsouprakos", "", 'Lost'),
    (16, "Backpack", "Black and blue Under Armour backpack, with keychain hanging off the front zipper", now(), now(), "Room 2023", "", "Casimer DeCusatis", 'Found'),
    (32, "Sunglasses", "Tortoise print Ray Ban sunglasses", now(), now(), "", "", "Rachel Ulicni", 'Found');
```

PHP:

```
    #Creates individual table for each hotlink(row) 
        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $results , MYSQLI_ASSOC ) )
        {
            $alink = '<A HREF=linkystuff.php?name=' . $row['name']. '>' . $row['name'] . '</A>' ;
            echo '<TR>' ;            
            echo '<TD>' . $row['id'] . '</TD>' ;
            echo '<TD>' . $row['create_date'] . '</TD>' ;
            echo '<TD>' . $row['status'] . '</TD>' ;
            echo '<TD ALIGN=right>' . $alink . '</TD>' ;
            echo '</TR>' ;
        }

        #End the table
        echo '</TABLE>';

        #Free up the results in memory
        mysqli_free_result( $results ) ;
    }
}

#Shows the records in presidents
function show_record($dbc, $name) {
    #Create a query to get the name and price sorted by price
    $query = 'SELECT id, location_id, name, description, create_date, update_date, room, owner, finder, status FROM stuff WHERE name = ' . $name ;
```

Comment: which query gives an error??

Comment: the query in the show_records function I assume, when I change the $name to 'name' at the end of the query it just displays the first line from the database regarding the cell phone, even if I clock on other links such as backpack or sunglasses

Comment: @Zeke - could you add a little more code? Where does `$row` come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to quote $name in your query

```
$query = 'SELECT id, location_id, name, description, create_date, update_date, room, owner, finder, status' .
    ' FROM stuff' .
    ' WHERE name = "' . $name . '"';
//                 ^             ^
```

But it would be better tu use prepared statements to prevent sql injection and others

```
$query = 'SELECT id, location_id, name, description, create_date, update_date, room, owner, finder, status' .
    ' FROM stuff' .
    ' WHERE name = ?';
$stmt = $mysqli_link->query($query); // or: mysqli_query($link, $query);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: that worked great thank you so much, but for some reason it will not recognize the first line in the sql regarding cell phone, it displays all the information for backpack and sunglasses but not cell phone... I appreciate the help more than you know

Comment: Did you check if the line is correct in your database? Do you get any error?

Comment: Actually just figured it out.. it won't let me put a space between cell phone, for  example, cellphone works but cell phone does not. I am going to do some research on how to fix this but thank you so much for your help

Comment: Maybe it is the url, see urlencode() and urldecode() in this case. A var_dump() at the right place can be handy.

Comment: @Zeke Just seen: You missed the quotes in your generating php code, in the code above it's $aLink = '<a href=...' - have a look at urlencode() anyway: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php